# Chrome Developer Tools> Open on all pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The above functionality is available on Firefox Firebug and is really useful when working with pages that are using popups/new tabs etc.

I can't see it in the usual places for Google Chrome and wondered if it was available? ... if so ... any pointers please :)

Thanks